# Selenium WebDriver Automation script for application Developed using NW.js Technology

Tags: node.js, selenium, webdriver, nw.js

Iam trying to Automate my application which is a standalone application build using NW.JS technologies. and based on chromium embedded framework
NW.JS is a desktop application with web technologies implementation.
The Application to be tested is actually embedded inside the Web Took Kit and looks like a normal window application.
It does not make use any of the traditional browsers(IE/Firefox/Chrome/Safari)
I automated the basic login functionality of my application using selenium web driver and python script and when i run it, it invokes my application but unable to identify the objects in the App.
I tried with other testing tools, like 
UFT
TestComplete
White
Ranorex
WinTask

All of these tools are invoking my application, but unable to identify the objects inside the App like login link etc.
when i use object spy,it always highlights the main window only and does not identifies the objects inside the application
My developer was saying that the app uses web view tag?
developer has given us the Chrome Dev tools, using which we can inspect the objects properties, but despite this i still see errors when i try to run my automation script developed in selenium python script
Not sure which testing framework and test automation tools will match my requirements
Any one can please guide me, Iam struggling with the Test Automation tools to make it identify the objects inside the application
The Application is built using CSS3.0,HTML5.0,JavaScript,C++ and node.js Technologies

Comment: Please your code or a [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as the errors you are encountering.

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: undefined is not a function
  (Session info: content shell=)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.13 (072d56ad45f528d86ca62d8709be879fd2e7644c),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver is extended by several broweser drivers which selenium supports including 3rd party browser drivers... Find your browser driver in the link http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ . and you should include that in your project otherwise it tries to trigger firefox driver which is inbuilt. If you dont find your browser driver type means selenium webdriver is not the one for you..... You should try some other automation tools